# Barracuda Email Encryption

Tags: c#, email, encryption

I need to encrypt an email using Barracuda. As i saw, they offer 2 clients for email encryption (hardware and cloud based)

https://www.barracuda.com/resources/Barracuda_Email_Security_Gateway_WP_Securing_Email_with_Email_Encryption_US

Since I'm not familiar with the topic, wanted to ask if there is any way if an E-mail can be encrypted with Barracuda via code behind? My case is C#, but an answer in any programming language will help, as i'm not sure if this can be achieved at all.

Comment: I suspect this will just be the usual S/MIME encryption, but applied automatically by Barraccuda's device acting as an SMTP gateway as email leaves your network. They'll want to interoperate with other systems after all.